# viewCount and commentCount for blogposts in sitefinity

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I need to display titles of all blogposts sorted by viewCount desc in one list and by commentsCount desc in another list. I have the following, but doesnt seem to work.....what am I doing wrong here......

```
protected void getBlogPosts()
{
        BlogsManager blogsManager = BlogsManager.GetManager();

        List<BlogPost> postsList = blogsManager.GetBlogPosts().Where(t => t.Status==ContentLifecycleStatus.Live).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxItemstoShow; i++)
        {


            BlogPost post = postsList[i];
            int commentsCount = post.Comments.Count;
            int viewCount = post.ViewsCount;
            plhBlogsList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class=\"post_titles_container\"><div class=\"newsitem\"><a href='/news/" + post.ItemDefaultUrl + "'>" + post.Title + "</a></div></div>"));
        }


}
```

commentsCount and viewCount always return 0, even when I have comments and views for a particular blogpost. Is this not the right way of looking for those counts?

Or is there a setting within Sitefinity dashboard that I need to turn on/off to make the counts work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is really specific to Sitefinity, you would be better off posting on their forum.

But a quick google search [returned this post](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/getting-comments-from-a-blog-post) which says to use something like:

```
commentsCount = blogsManager.GetComments().Count();
```